# Cannot read property '_index' of undefined ChartistJs for value 0 or null

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, web-deployment, chartist.js

I am using **[chartistJS](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/)** for charts on my webpage.
I have learned the 'onClick' function in the options provided by chartist.

Please find my code below:

```
 public horizontalBarchartoptions = {
      'onClick' : function (evt, item) {
        var index = item[0]['_index']
        var reportId = latestScanReportID[index];
        routingFunct.navigate(["./resultPage/"+reportId]);
      },
      tooltips: {
              callbacks: {
                  label: function(tooltipItem) {
                      return  " "+ Number(tooltipItem.xLabel)+" issue(s)";
                  }
              }
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Volume'
              }, 
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Density',
              ticks: {
                  mirror: true,
                  autoSkip: false,
                  padding: -30,
                  fontColor: '#fff'
                }}],
            xAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: '# Issues'
              }, 
              ticks: {
                min: 0,
                userCallback: function(label, index, labels) {
                  // when the floored value is the same as the value we have a whole number
                  if (Math.ceil(label) === label) {
                      return label;
                  }
                }                
            },
            }]
         }       
        };
```

When clicked on a bar the above code redirects to a result page for that particular bar id
below is an image for the same:
[In this image when clicked on scan 1 - scan 4 it is redirected to results page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN8Gm.png)
When clicked on Scan 5 it throws the following exception since the value of **Scan 5** is **0**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_index' of undefined
```

I can start the axis label from -1 but that is not the preferable solution, Can you please suggest a different approach to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If my answer was useful please upvote and mark as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to at least handling when 'item' has no elements:

```
 public horizontalBarchartoptions = {
      'onClick' : function (evt, item) {
        if (item != null && item != undefined) {
           if (item.length > 0) {
              var index = item[0]['_index']
              var reportId = latestScanReportID[index];
              routingFunct.navigate(["./resultPage/"+reportId]);
           }
        }
      },
      tooltips: {
              callbacks: {
                  label: function(tooltipItem) {
                      return  " "+ Number(tooltipItem.xLabel)+" issue(s)";
                  }
              }
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Volume'
              }, 
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Density',
              ticks: {
                  mirror: true,
                  autoSkip: false,
                  padding: -30,
                  fontColor: '#fff'
                }}],
            xAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: '# Issues'
              }, 
              ticks: {
                min: 0,
                userCallback: function(label, index, labels) {
                  // when the floored value is the same as the value we have a whole number
                  if (Math.ceil(label) === label) {
                      return label;
                  }
                }                
            },
            }]
         }       
        };
```

Hope this helps.